# SQL Server for Daily group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Me, little fresh again. I want to group a daily data for the excel data use, here is my data:

I have 10 cage with different staff. since some of them is part-time staff, I need to present the data to record each month each day the number of staff in each cage.

```
Date       | Cage No |  staff name   
-----------+---------+-----------------    
2017-11-01 | AA001   |  Jeff.C
2017-11-01 | AA001   |  Mary.H
2017-11-01 | AA001   |  Christina.J
2017-11-01 | AA001   |  Susan.I
2017-11-01 | AA002   |  Jeff.B
2017-11-01 | AA002   |  Mary.L
ETC
2017-11-27 | AA010   | Billy.K
2017-11-27 | AA010   | Bosco.G
```

The result I want

```
Date       | Cage No. | Staff NO.
-----------+----------+-----------------    
2017-11-01 | AA001    |    5
2017-11-01 | AA002    |    7
2017-11-01 | AA003    |    8
etc
2017-11-02 | AA001    |  6
2017-11-02 | AA002    |  8
etc
2017-11-27 | AA010    | 10
```

I use this SQL code:

```
select [date], [cage no], count([staff])
from [table]
where date between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-27'
group by [cage no]
```

It's not work, and I think "group by" only can show the group by column with single row. Do I need to use " count (case when ...then 1 ) " to define all the staff belong to which cage?

or I can use different way to do the same result?

Thank you so much!! please please please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [date] on group by

```
select [date], [cage no], count([staff])
from [table]
where date between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-27'
group by [date],[cage no]
order by [date],[cage no]
```

Comment: Thank Youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu sooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! wowowwowowowowowowowow

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
ORDER BY column_name(s);
```

You should write the column_name in group by which column_name you write on the 
select statement.

```
select [date], [cage no], count([staff])
from [table]
where date between '2017-11-01' and '2017-11-27'
group by [date],[cage no]
order by [date] asc,[cage no] asc
```